# Need some help understanding regex

Tags: regex, wordpress

I'm trying to get my head around using wordpress `preg_` functions to filter strings using regex. Mainly just testing at this stage to try and understand how it all works.

So, I have this arbitrary string:-

```
random text [cbshort text="my text setting"] more random text
[cbshort2 text="my text setting"]some enclosed text[/cbshort2] yet
more text [cbshort text="my text setting"] some text on the end
```

which contains some shortcodes enclosed in square brackets. I'm trying to use regex to extract the shortcode sections from the string.

I tried using the following expression:

```
/\[cbshort.*\]/
```

Which seems to capture everything between the first `[cbshort` and the last `]` in the string. I don't understand why its ignoring all the `]` between the first and last. However, when I try:-

```
/\[cbshort.*?\]/
```

It seems to work correctly; it captures the individual sections between the square brackets.

I know the `?` represents optional characters. But in the context of my example, I don't understand why my first example doesn't work and the second does.

Can anybody shed some light on it.

Comment: `*?` is a *lazy* quantifier matching 0 or more occurrences of the quantified subpattern. A single "atom", not an optional `*`.

Comment: don't parse shortcodes by hand, use a battle-tested library: https://github.com/thunderer/Shortcode

Comment: Thanks chaps. I didnt know much regards lazy and greedy quantifiers. This is certainly enough to move me on.

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk. Thanks for the library link. That will come in handy. But for now, Im trying to do this myself just for the sake of understanding.